# How to create different product view pages and echo those in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, foreach

I'm looking for advise or a standard way of doing this that will still allow me to use my same products page.

I am creating an e-commerce site. As of now, I do not have many products, so all of my products are going to be on one page called "Products". The way I am doing this is via a php foreach loop, like this:

```
<?php   
// Loop to display all products
foreach($products as $id => $product) {
?>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="productpiccontainer">
            <?php echo "<img src='productpics/". $row['img'] ."' alt='Product Pic'>"; ?>
        </div>      
        <p><?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'] . "</a>"; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo "$" . $product['price']; ?> </p>                                      
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now my issue is that my products need different product view pages. I may have a product with different colors or sizes and one product that is a standard product that you don't have to choose those options.

I'm getting to the product view page from this line of code...

```
<p><?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'] . "</a>"; ?></p>
```

A solution I thought might work is to create another field in my form of my admin add product page (that adds the product to my products page). I thought that if I created different view product pages like: viewProduct.php viewProduct1.php viewProduct2.php

and then echoed out that link into the foreach loop that I could do what I'm trying to do.

The issue is when I try adding the link to my field for my form in the admin add product page, I get errors when trying to submit it. I have it structured something like this...

```
<div class="field">
<label for="viewproduct_type">View Product Type</label>
<select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
    <option value="Not Selected">Not Selected</option>
    <option value="<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
    <option value="Option">Option</option>
</select>
```

I have not put anything is for option yet because I don't have another page.

Why can I not send a link like this to my database? Also is there a better way to do this then what I am trying to do?

Comment: This an advice, take it as you will. I've dealt a lot with e-commerce sites, if you plan on building one yourself, don't and use an already available solution. If you do plan on building on yourself, avoid mixing php and html, you'll curse outloud in 6 months from now. Get a templating engine and use that.

Comment: Why do you say that about the php/html thing? I am building this site to learn coding. I wouldn't learn nearly as much with an already available solution, but I might transfer over to Magneto or something one I am up and running and need a better system. Any ideas on my issue I am having though?

Comment: If this is for learning purposes, then have at it. Point still stands, don't mix html and php, it's bad practice that you'll carry down the road. As for you problem, it's a pretty easy fix. Have a main template and extend that one for different products.

Comment: @Andrew So if I have a product that I need to have an option box for colors and then an option box for sizes, how can I get that to not show if the product is standard and doesn't have any of those?